# problems creating json file from arrays

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, underscore.js, fs

I was trying to put this playlist file like the file below in a albums.json file but having trouble with this. Also I would like this json object to be uniq . if anyone can point me in the right direction I will thanks you so much.

m3u file playlist.m3u

```
 #EXTM3U
 file:///Users/user/Music/Various Artists/El Mejor Album de Opera del Mundo/1-01 Verdi_ La Traviata.mp3
 file:///Users/user/Music/Various Artists/El Mejor Album de Opera del Mundo/1-02 Gioacchino Rossini_ El Barbero de Sevilla.mp3
 file:///Users/user/Music/Various Artists/El Mejor Album de Opera del Mundo/1-03 Giacomo Puccini_ La Bohe%CC%80me_ Che Gelida manina.mp3
 file:///Users/user/Music/Various Artists/El Mejor Album de Opera del Mundo/1-04 Giacomo Puccini_ La Bohe%CC%80me_ Si%CC%80. Mi chiamano Mimi%CC%80.mp3
 file:///Users/user/Music/Various Artists/El Mejor Album de Opera del Mundo/1-05 Mascagni_ L'amico Fritz.mp3
 file:///Users/user/Music/Various Artists/El Mejor Album de Opera del Mundo/1-06 Verdi_ Nabucco.mp3
```

...

```
var allLines = fs.readFileSync('playlist.m3u').toString().split('\n');


 fs.writeFileSync('albums.json', '', function(){console.log('file is empty');});


allLines.forEach(function (line) {

  line = line.replace('file:///Users/user/Music/', '');
  line = line.replace('#EXTM3U','');
  line = urlencode.decode(line); // decoding some chars
  let arr = [];
  let savedData = [];
  let linex = [];
  arr = line.split("/");
  linex["artist"] = arr[0];
  linex["album"] = arr[1];
  linex["size"] = "600x600";

  console.log(linex); // till here it print what i want to print

  savedData.push(linex); // this is not inserting the array
  savedData = _.uniq(savedData); // this is either notworking, because fails before

  fs.writeFile("albums.json",JSON.stringify(savedData),function(err){
    if(err) console.error(err);
    else console.log('Data saved to albums.json file');
  });

});
```

the result file in this case is :

```
[[]]
```

if have plenty different results but not a proper json file with object. what i'doing wrong guys?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your problem:** Your code has two small bugs. It is (1)reinitializing the array `let savedData = []` and (2) rewriting your output file `fs.writeFile()` at every `.forEach()` iteration.

**simple solution:** Move both outside the `forEach` code; the initialization before, and the write after the iterator.

**refactored solution:** Or simply use the more succint `.filter` and `.map` methods of array

```
let d = fs.readFileSync('playlist.m3u','utf8')
  .split('\n')
  .map( l => l.trim() )
  .filter( l => !l.startsWith('#') )
  .map( l => {
    let [artist, album, title ] = l
      .replace('file:///Users/user/Music/','')
      .split('/');
    return { artist, album, title, size:'600x600' };
  });

fs.writeFileSync('albums.json',JSON.stringify(d),'utf8');
```

Comment: thanks , I have edited the way I use it. I also realized what you point out about moving out o forEach, :(

Comment: btw ,  "filter( l => !l. startsWith("#") )" suppose to remove  #EXTM3U not working , any ideas? i'm new to this sintax u used

Comment: Yes, it does... maybe is there a blank space at the beginning of the line?

Comment: You could first `.trim()` all the lines. Add a `.map( l => l.trim() )` between the `.split()` and the `.filter()`

Answer (score 0):

It should be pushing it,
The error is that you are reinitializing the variable savedData in every iteration of forEach which makes it an empty array again.

Just remove the `let savedData = [];` out of the method passed to forEach

Comment: sorry that was a mistake